# How to close the current module and start another one without causing any errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried doing;

```
os.system('python currentfile.py')

sys.exit() or quit()
```

but instead of closing, the current python file just becomes unresponsive causing an undesired 'not responding' loop. The first file is a sign-in module which is supposed to open another py file and then close itself but it doesn't seem to work at all. I've also tried the subprocess.Popen method and the result is still not what I want.

Comment: `os.exec*` is probably what you want to look into ... or `subprocess.Popen` with `daemon=True`

Comment: Why do you want to execute your pythonfile like this ? Why not importing the python module and execute the code ?

Comment: @azro the modules are separate tkinter windows so need them to be running in a selected sequence. And I tried creating multiple windows in the same module but it is much trickier than this method.